# Does Plotly libraries facilitate drill-able graphs and dashboards?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.js, plotly-python

Plotly gives a great range of chart types with event support, but is there out of the box support for manipulating the underlying dataset's being graphed on a dashboard with linked charts that will facilitate creating drillable dashboards?

Answer (score 0):

How about https://plot.ly/products/dash/?

Is that what you're looking for?